# Summation: different answer than in book.

Tags: calculus, summation

So here I have two summations,

$$O_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_{k})\cdot \Delta x  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,B_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k})\cdot \Delta x \\ 
$$ $$f(x)=1+0,1x^2$$ 
End points are :  [1, 6] and: $$x_{0}(=a), x_{1},\,...\, ,x_{5} (=b)$$
 where:

$$O_{5}\approx 10.5  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, B_{5}\approx 14.0$$

Yet I keep getting the wrong value out of this formula.. Till now the only values I got are: $$O_{5}= 8  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, B_{5}= 10.5$$

It would really help me if someone could write this out and show me where I'm wrong.

My answer was the following:

$$O_{5}=\sum_{k=0}^{4}(1+0.1\cdot k^2)\cdot 1  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,B_{5}=\sum_{k=1}^{5}(1+0.1\cdot k^2)\cdot 1 \\ 
$$

(edit: Again, sorry, I get different values this time. Still not correct.)

Comment: You have to give more details

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot.  That's all information. (see edit)

Comment: put that info in question rather than comments

Comment: We'd also need to know what the endpoints of the interval are from which the $x_k$ are chosen, so that we have a way of calculating $\Delta x$ and $x_k$.

Comment: What is the comma notation? And what is $\Delta x$?

Comment: Sorry! hopefully that's all.. Highly appreciated.

Comment: 10.5 and 14.0 look correct. Unless you tell us *how* you got your values, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Let me write it in latex, one sec please.

Comment: @Bowser: $x_k = 1 + k$, not $x_k = k$.

Comment: @MartinR Can you explain why that is? Because of the subscript?

Comment: @Bowser $x_k = a + k\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}$. In this case, $x_k = 1 + k\cdot\frac{6-1}{5}=1+k$.

Comment: Oh! I see now, awesome. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$
 a = x_{0},  x_{1},\,...\, ,x_{n} = b
$$
are $(n+1)$ equidistant points then the difference between two consecutive
is $(b-a)/n$ and the general formula is
$$
 x_k = a + k \frac{b-a}{n} \text{ for } k= 0, \dots, n \, .
$$

In your case $x_k = 1 + k$ for $k = 0, \dots, 5$,
and then
$$
O_{5}=\sum_{k=0}^{4} \bigl(1+0.1\cdot (1+k)^2 \bigr)\cdot 1
$$
gives  the expected result.